# Is contraction or dilation linked to the moving of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, particle-physics

I have read recently an article about the discovery of a Rydberg molecule. And there was a place were says that "the researchers cooled that a molecule to 100 nano Kelvin". I understand that they cooled it to slow down the electrons and to have accuracy in beaming them with a laser. My question is: Has the speed of electrons a connection with the contraction and dilation of an atom, molecule, body, etc.?

[Source of article](http://futurism.com/a-new-type-of-atomic-bond-has-been-discovered/)

Comment: Citing the article would be good form. I suspect they cooled the molecule to eliminate thermal broadening in their spectroscopy, as well as help keep the molecules in a Rydberg state by limiting collisional de-excitation. As for the electrons, atomic and molecular orbitals don't have a 'speed', generally speaking. (Not to say that a Rydberg-like wave packet does not have a time-varying position).

Comment: I have cited it now. I suppose that would be good for understanding to learn more about a Rydberg state and quantum physics.

Comment: Do you have in mind relativistic contraction or dilation, or do you have in mind the change the effective change in the radius of the atom as the electron moves from one orbital to another, or do you have  in mind something else altogether?

Comment: I have in mind the effective change in the radius of an atom.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation value for the squared radius of a Rydberg atom is *much* larger than that for a atoms in the ground state or a low angular-momentum excited state. That is, those atoms are bigger than the ordinary size.

So why does the article make an point of the cooling procedure?

Because Rydberg atoms are *very* easy to ionize and even the thermal jostling of ordinary temperature would do it.

Like this: the energy of a hydrogren atom is 
$$\left(-13.6\,\mathrm{eV}\right)\frac{1}{N^2} \;,$$ 
where $N$ is the principle quantum number. It's negative because it is bound and it take that much energy to ionize the atom. Because the angular momentum state can be no higher than the principle quantum number and a Rydberg atom is one with a very high angular momentum quantum number they must have very high $N$ (a few tens or even hundreds). But that means that Rydberg atoms are *very* easy to ionize.

Now the temperature of a material is closely related to the average amount of energy bound up in each atoms and getting transferred from one to another by the random motion of the atoms and molecules. Quantitatively we have
$$ E_{avg} =  k_b T \;,$$
where $k_b = 1.38 \times 10^{-23} \,\mathrm{m^2 \, kg \, s^{-2} \, K^{-1}}$; at which means that the average energy at room temperature is about one-foutieth of an electron volt. If the ionization energy of an atom is only a few times the average energy associated with the local temperature it will be ionized over relatively short time periods.

So the experimenter who wants to study Rydberg atoms in the lab arranges to have the atoms placed in a very low temperature environment where the atoms will not be disrupted by the simple thermal motion of the environment.